# After "source .profile" the variable in a new terminal is still empty

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, xfce4-terminal

One of the applications requires `JAVA_HOME` variable. Java is installed. 
 In `~/.profile` I have this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/share/perl6/vendor/bin:/home/arch/.local/bin:$PATH"

JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/default"
export JAVA_HOME

PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

I've added the last 3 lines. Then I ran `source ~/.profile` and the same terminal window it showed  the `/usr/lib/jvm/default` which was correct. However, in the new terminal it showed nothing. What did I forget?

Comment: did you open the new terminal *after* you edited your `.profile`?

Answer (score 4):

.profile is run at login but a new terminal window is not a login and instead runs ~/.bashrc.

if you log out of your session and login again your .profile will have the desired effect and your new terminal sessions after the login will inherit these settings from the initial login.

Comment: should java_home include the bin directory?